# Flutter how to convert CustomMultiChildLayout to CustomSingleChildLayout

Tags: flutter, dart

I am placing markers on an image using CustomMultiChildLayout. But now I am trying to convert this to CustomSingleChildLayout because I only need one marker. But I can't get it work. I am using this code:

```
late var chips = <ChipEntry>[];
late var marker = ChipEntry(offset: const Offset(5, 3));

CustomMultiChildLayout(
                    delegate: FloorPlanDelegate(
                      chips: chips,
                      transformationController: transformationController,
                    ),
                    children: [
                      for (int index = 0; index < chips.length; index++)
                        LayoutId(id: index, child: _button(index)),
                    ],
                  ),


class FloorPlanDelegate extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate {
  FloorPlanDelegate({
    required this.chips,
    required this.transformationController,
  }) : super(
            relayout: transformationController); 
  final List<ChipEntry> chips;
  final TransformationController transformationController;

  @override
  void performLayout(ui.Size size) {
    int id = 0;
    final constraints = BoxConstraints.loose(size);
    final matrix = transformationController.value;
    for (final chip in chips) {
      final size = layoutChild(id, constraints);
      final offset = MatrixUtils.transformPoint(matrix, chip.offset) -
          size.center(Offset.zero);
      positionChild(id, offset);
      id++;
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(covariant MultiChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

And I have tried to change it like this:

```
late var chips = <ChipEntry>[];
late var marker = ChipEntry(offset: const Offset(5, 3));

CustomSingleChildLayout(
                    delegate: FloorPlanDelegate(
                      marker: marker,
                      transformationController: transformationController,
                    ),child: _button(),
                    
                  ),


class FloorPlanDelegate extends SingleChildLayoutDelegate {
  FloorPlanDelegate({
    required this.marker,
    required this.transformationController,
  }) : super(
            relayout: transformationController); 
  final ChipEntry marker;
  final TransformationController transformationController;

  @override
  void performLayout(ui.Size size) {
    final constraints = BoxConstraints.loose(size);
    final matrix = transformationController.value;
      final size = layoutChild(id, constraints);
      final offset = MatrixUtils.transformPoint(matrix, chip.offset) -
          size.center(Offset.zero);
      positionChild(id, offset);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(covariant SingleChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

But I get errors and don't know how to continue. Does anyone know how I can solve this?

[image]